# Couchbase key not expring after giving a TTL via C#

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase

I'm using the Atomic 'Increment' function provided by the C# driver for Couchbase which accepts a parameter for passing the expiry as a TimeSpan.

I'm passing the value in the expiry parameter as **TimeSpan.FromMinutes(value)** , but still after refreshing the couchbase web console, the key does not get deleted after the set time.

Here is the sample code

```
 IOperationResult<ulong> incrementResult;

 incrementResult = myBucket.Increment(strKeyName, 1, 1,TimeSpan.FromMinutes(dblTTL));
```

In the code above variable '**dblTTL**' is the **Minute** Property of the **TimeSpan** variable.

.NET Sdk version - 2.0 , 
Couchbase Dll version - 2.0.3.0

Any help on this issue will be appreciated !

Comment: What version of the .Net SDK are you using?

When you say it does not get deleted, how are you looking at the object? I ask as when a TTL expires, Couchbase marks it for deletion and the next cleanup cycle it will get deleted. but there are ways to still see it in the console.

Also, what are you setting the value to?

Comment: @Kirk - have updated my answer above .. !

Comment: @Kirk - i found the solution, checkout my answer, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, i just figured out the solution.

1. i made use of the **TimeSpan.TotalMinutes** property instead of **TimeSpan.Minutes** as **TotalMinutes** returns the value as a double which is accurate to the nearest millisecond as compared to **Minutes** which returns just the minutes part of the total duration as an int.
2. secondly, a key which is initially created without setting a TTL using the atomic **increment()** function , but later on when trying to **increment()** the same key now by passing a TTL value did not expire the key.

so if i have to set a TTL to any key using the atomic **increment()** function i have to make sure that i set its TTL when i create that key for the first time, and not while updating its value later on.